# LWC lightning-record-form and onChange events

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

[image]I'm stuck, I've been trying to make sense of a simple component that should console.log the value of a *lightning-record-form* on the developer console.

My .html file is quite simple

```
        <lightning-record-form object-api-name=Account layout-type="Full" columns="2"
               onsubmit={handleSubmit} onchange={handleChange}>
        </lightning-record-form>
```

My JS is also really simple, I can get the value of the field that is being changed through event.details but I cannot get the target nor currentTarget of the element that is being changed.

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class Aplwctest extends LightningElement {
@api name;

handleChange(event) {
    let clause = event.target;
    let value = event.detail;

    console.log('Clause', clause);
    console.log('Value', value);

  }
}
```

Additional info, the lightning-record-form is being called within a modal. Each change is caught but the name of the element is not available as you can see from the attached image.

I'm trying to avoid adding individually each field to leverage the dynamic nature of the component.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I've linked a duplicate answer that explains why this happens. You can capture the full record during `onsubmit`, but there's no documented way to get the values out before that time.